# How to get m4a file from recorded audio for API in Swift?

Tags: swift, post, avfoundation

Goal: I want to record audio for 10 seconds, get the audio recording file and send it in a post request.

What I have done: I am able to record audio for 10 seconds using this code:

```
var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

func setupAV() {
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.recordTapped)))
                } else {
                    // failed to record!
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}

@objc func recordTapped() {
    let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]

    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 10)
        print("RECORDING")
    } catch {
        print("audio failed to record")
    }

}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("DONE")
}
```

What I need to do: I need to get this audio recording as an m4a file and send it in a post request. How can I do this? Please let me know if you need any other information! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export the recording using `AVAssetExportSession`. Here is a nice method that will do it for you:

```
func export(fileType: AVFileType = .m4a, completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: recordingFileURL))
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else { return }
    exportSession.outputFileType = fileType
    exportSession.metadata = asset.metadata
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.outputURL = exportOutputURL
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        print("Export finished.")
        completion()
    }
}
```

Where `exportOutputURL` can be any URL that you create in the documents directory. For example, we can define it as a computed property:

```
var exportOutputURL: URL? {
    let pathURL = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    return pathURL?.appendingPathComponent("my_exported_recording")
}
```

You will now have the exported m4a file in your `exportOutputURL`.

Depending on what your API expects the parameter to be, you can convert into data like so:

```
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: exportOutputURL)
} catch { ... }
```

And to a `base64` string:

```
let base64String = data.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help!!! Giving it a shot right now.

Comment: What do I use as the recordingFileURL and the exportOutputURL? Could you give me an example of how to use this given my code? Appreciate the help!!!

Comment: For the `recordingFileURL` use the file that you are recording to, in your code it's `audioFilename`. For the `exportOutputURL` you can use any URL in the documents directory. For example in the context of your code you could use something like: `getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("exported_recording")`

Comment: What does the exportOutputURL mean? Is that where I should set Data(contentsOf: fileURL)? Should I set the fileURL equal to the exportOutputURL I set?

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully it makes more sense now. Define `exportOutputURL` as a computed property as shown in your class, and indeed you can also use it as the `contentsOfURL` when creating the data object.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much for your detailed response!

Comment: Prefix file:// is added in path, not allowing to upload file. What's wrong above, please update as per swift 5